# Name of alternate timeline short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, timeline

In the story the man helps with someone's estate and receives a custom clock. He discovers the clock maker lives in the woods outside town and visits him. After leaving the place at night he gets lost in the woods. He ends up at an abandoned military base and I believe is captured. He wakes up in the morning and can leave his cell. The base is abandoned and he is in an alternate timeline.